# Simply connected quasi-split groups are generated by unipotent subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am particularly interested in the special unitary groups defined over the field $\mathbb C((X))$ with the conjugation $X\rightarrow -X$.

> Are these groups generated by some unipotent subgroups?
>
> Does these groups splits over a tamely ramified extension of $\mathbb C((X^2))$ ?

Many thanks

Comment: You really mean (quasi-split) special unitary groups over $\mathbf{C}(\!(X^2)\!)$ (a field with a unique quadratic extension): if $k'/k$ is a quadratic Galois extension of fields and $(V', h')$ is a finite-dimensional non-degenerate hermitian space over $k'$ then ${\rm{SU}}(h')$ is "defined over $k$": it is a $k$-subgroup of the Weil restriction ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}({\rm{GL}}(V'))$. Steinberg proved the Kneser-Tits property (i.e., $H(k)$ is generated by $U(k)$'s for unipotent radicals $U$ of minimal parabolic $k$-subgroups) for quasi-split simply connected groups $H$ over any field $k$, so: yes.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Could you give a reference please?

Comment: I don't remember the relevant article title offhand and do not have convenient access to books/libraries at the moment, but hopefully someone else with better access will be able to provide it (or try skimming Steinberg's Collected Works, or write to Philippe Gille).

Comment: Another quastion: Does the special unitary groups splits over tamely ramified extension of $k$? thanks

Comment: What are you assuming about $k$ (you speak of "tamely ramified", a property that holds for all extensions of complete discretely-valued fields in residue characteristic 0 such as in your original question)?  If you mean for $k$ to be a complete discretely-valued field with perfect residue field of characteristic $p$ then the answer is "no" when $p=2$ (obstruction is the quadratic Galois extension $k'/k$ being wild) but "yes" when $p\ne 2$ (since Steinberg showed it is quasi-split over the maximal unramified extension, and then splitting $k'/k$ on top of that does the job).

Comment: Yes $k$ is like in my original question. So I think the answer is yes by what you have said?

Comment: Sure, but in the setting of your question (so residue characteristic 0) *all* finite extensions of $k$ are tamely ramified, so there is no substance in the assertion that it splits over a tamely ramified extension of $k$: every connected reductive group $G$ does so in that case since they all split over some finite extension (depending on $G$).  The affirmative answer for complete discretely-valued $k$ with perfect residue field of characteristic $p>2$ has a lot of substance (but is not the setting of your original question).